# PhoneGap 2.6.0 and Kendo UI Mobile external links

Tags: cordova, kendo-mobile

Using Kendo UI Mobile v2013.1.319 and PhoneGap 2.6.0 (iOs), I'm no longer able to open links in the Safari browser.

This worked well on previous versions:

```
<a href="http://apache.org" data-rel="external" target="_blank">
```

But now it still opens in the same webview as the app itself.

Any tips how to force the links to open externally? Preferably without using javascript, as the HTML for the links is loaded dynamically through an external datasource.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can use Cordova [InAppBrowser](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Comment: The IAB works fine, but the <a> links are loaded externally, so preferably it should be done without using javascript. But the way it looks so far is that I'll call the ChildBrowser from the a onClick tag.

Comment: well in fact the onclick attribute uses javascript :P

Comment: Hehe, yes, so the conclusion so far is that there's no way around it.